# Different php-fpm pools in single nginx vhost

Tags: nginx, php, php-fpm

I searched for a while online but couldn't succeed. My problem is as follows:

I want to use different php-fpm pools in one nginx vhost based conditionally on the nature of the request but couldn't find a way to configure the `location ~ \.php$ {...}` part of my vhost config to support two different worker pools.

Only solution I figured out is redirecting the web request to another nginx site.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can work along the following principle:

```
set $upstream /path/to/defaultfpm-socket;

location /first {
    set $upstream /path/to/fpm1-socket;
}

location /second {
    set $upstream /path/to/fpm2-socket;
}

fastcgi_pass $upstream;
```

So, here we set the `$upstream` variable to the PHP5-FPM socket we want to use depending on the location (part of the URI). We then use the variable with `fastcgi_pass` to pass the request to that PHP5-FPM instance.

`location` rules can use normal nginx matching rules, like regex, prefix etc. matching. It is a good idea to set a default value so that requests are always parsed.

You need to also include other FastCGI statements in the configuration.